# Laravel Nova Model relationship 2 or more models

Tags: laravel, model, frameworks, relationship, laravel-nova

I'm using the **Laravel Nova framework** and I'm having difficulty using relationships when it comes to visualization (index, and show methods).

Ex: I have a model called User (id, name address_id), it has a relationship with Address (id, street, state_id), and Address has a relationship with State (id, name), all use **belongsTo**.

How do I show State in the User profile? The way I know of is **$ user-> address-> state-> name**, but how do I do that with Nova? Or would you have to create a state_id field in User as well? (that would be awful)

Answer (score 1):

Nova support callbacks for field value description. Try this one:

```
Text::make('state', function($resource) {
                // Some code for receiving your state data
                return $resource->address->state; // as example
            })->exceptOnForms(),
```

For more details, read this [Computed Fields](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#computed-fields)

And this [Dynamic Field Methods](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#dynamic-field-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [displayUsing](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html)

```
 BelongsTo::make('State name', 'address', Address::class)                      
       ->displayUsing(function () {
            return $this->address->state->name;
        })
```